# how can i increase current index in angular for each loop when new record is get added in angular?

Tags: angular

I've added new record to my existing table,here record is getting added but id does not increment automatically, I write  code as bellow I'm not getting where it goes wrong?  How do I increment count of id?
 I am new to angular,if anyone knows solution please help me out...
thanks

**template :**

```
<tbody>
          <tr style="color:dimgrey;" *ngFor="let cmt of lstcomments; let index=i">
            <th scope="row">{{ cmt.id }}</th>
            <td>{{cmt.name}}</td>
            <td>{{cmt.email}}</td>
            <td class="icon-style">           
              <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="..\assets\image\trash.png"></span> 
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**popup for adding record:**

```
 <div class="modal fade addNewInputs" id="modalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAdd"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
              <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold text-primary ml-5">Add new user</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close text-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-3">
             <div class="md-form mb-5">
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="inputName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control validate" id="newAttributeName" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.name" name="newAttributeName">               
              </div>         
              <div class="md-form mb-5">
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="inputemail">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="inputSalary" class="form-control validate" id="newAttributeEmail" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.email" name="newAttributeEmail" >                
              </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center buttonAddFormWrapper">
              <button (click)="addNewuser()" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block buttonAdd" data-dismiss="modal">Add form              
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="float-right">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-sm " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdd"><i class="fa fa-plus" ></i>Add</a>
      </div>
```

**ts :**

```
 addNewuser() {
      this.lstcomments.push(this.newAttribute);
      this.newAttribute = {};
  }
```

Comment: you're not setting the id anywhere? and I'm not sure how the index is related to this?

Comment: try with this `this.lstcomments = [...this.lstcomments, this.newAttribute];`

Comment: I want to increase count of id when record get added to table

Comment: let index=i? it's the other way let i = index

Comment: The posts lacks [mre] IMO

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting id any where in this specified code. But you can do that by using **`index`**.

```
 <tr style="color:dimgrey;" *ngFor="let cmt of lstcomments; let index=i">
       <th scope="row">{{ i+1 }}</th>
       <td>{{cmt.name}}</td>
       <td>{{cmt.email}}</td>
       <td class="icon-style">           
       <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="..\assets\image\trash.png"></span> 
       </td>
  </tr>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a key for id and add the value to the key before push

```
addNewuser() {
      this.newAttribute.id=this.lstcomments.count++;
      this.lstcomments.push(this.newAttribute);
      this.newAttribute = {};
  }
```

this may help for you

Comment: If this not help provide me the sample list of array lstcomments this will help others to solve your issue, try to create a fiddle/stackblitz will help to debug your code

Comment: Thanks,but this is not helpful.  I am getting that lstcomments data from this api- apiurl="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

Comment: Try to provide your code in https://stackblitz.com and send let me check for u

Comment: is not `this.newAttribute.id=this.lstcomments.length;`? BTW, you need a function that return an object, not an object itself. If newAttribute is an object, when you push to the array, you're pushing the same object